# Poorly installed drywall anchors (by me)

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I was trying to install drywall anchors to hold curtain rods. I used a drill bit to make small holes and screwed the drywall anchors into the the holes by hand. A couple went fine on one side of the window. On the other side of the window I tried the same thing but the hole ended up breaking apart and now the drywall anchor just spins and does not hold well. Is there a way I can fix these holes so a new anchor will work or another way to hold the screws in place?

[image: horrible holes I made]

Here are the holes I made and am hoping to fix. (The picture is sideways)

thanks In advance!

Comment: Are you sure, sure, sure you can't screw into studs? Curtain rails tend to be quite long, so you should cross several. Curtains also tend to have quite heavy, dynamic loadings...

Comment: To add onto @SomeoneSomewhere's comment, there should be a stud to either side of the window. You shouldn't really need to use anchors, at least on the sides. Maybe in the middle, if the rod is long enough to warrant brackets in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many types of anchors. I suspect you used the basic cheap plastic plugs. I'd look to the various expanding or toggling types and simply use the same holes.

Otherwise, get some setting type joint compound and press it in firmly. Knife it off and allow it to cure thoroughly before a light sanding.

Comment: What did I do wrong that caused the drywall to crumble instead of hold firm? I used plastic drywall anchors that come to a sharp point.

Comment: I have probably set thousands of drywall anchors... sometimes they work; sometimes they don't. The only tangible thing I can think of is that you may have hit actual wood, which will prevent the anchor from working as intended.

Comment: Too much torque (stripped it out), something behind the anchor, too much/not enough force... tons of options. I've found metal ones a bit more reliable, but you really want toggle or molly bolts for heavier stuff.